# How to get Google analytics data in chart

Tags: php, html, charts, google-analytics-api

I want to get `Google Analytics` data in any chart using `PHP`

I have Created a project in my account and I have

> tracking code
>
> all credentials of google Auth.

I have follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/)
my tracking code is here

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

but I don't know what to do further

Comment: Can you please tell us what error you are getting with the above code ?

Comment: Error 401 (OAuth2 Error)!!1

Comment: Kindly check your Oauth Credentials. . . .

Comment: i have check my credentials but throws same error.

Comment: try going to https://analytics.google.com/analytics anything else you are going to have to code yourself using the api.   Either way this question is to broad please show us what you have done to solve your problem.

Comment: i am getting data to amchart

Comment: i have include Google library.but it throws Auth error. i have auth credential file and it's downloaded from my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying to this one
first download the .12 
in your Authentication add sdndsuidds-fkmfsdfdsf-545.p12 file 
check this code in your file

```
$google_account = array(
  'email'   => 'your-project-email@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  'key'     => file_get_contents('file-name.p12'),
  'profile' => 'profil-id'
);
```